# proper use of quotes

Tags: bash

I want to achieve this with bash:

```
for i in {1..2}
do
for j in {1..2}
do
echo $i $j >> tmp.txt
done
done

cat tmp.txt
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

However I want to do it like this with the echo variable inside quotes:

```
cmd="
for i in {1..2};
do for j in {1..2};
do echo \$i "\$j" '\$i' "'\$j'" \$i "'$j'" \'$i\' \"$j\" >> tmp.txt;
done;
done
"
eval $cmd
```

I can't seem to get the quotes right. Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Thank you!

Comment: Better provide an expected output. And when asking help, indentation is not just an option.

Comment: I can't help but notice that the `\$j` is black in the StackOverflow code rendering.  I don't know why, but it might have something to do with your problem.  then again, it might not.

Comment: Hi sputnick. I did provide an expected output with cat tmp.txt. I'm not sure if I understand your comment about indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use single quotes and be sure to put a semicolon before each `done`.

```
cmd='for i in {1..2}; do
for j in {1..2}; do
echo $i $j >> tmp.txt;
done;
done'
eval $cmd
```